# MySQL query to get the names of column where the value is blank for a particular row

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQl table with 5 columns and with most of them containing nothing (not even null). Objective is to find out the names of columns which do not have a valid data for a particular row.

[image]

Here for row number 5 column nameMusicCompany is empty hence query should return only this column name when executed for id = 5.

Result of the desired query should look like:

id  | name_of_column

5   | nameMusicCompany

6   | nameMusicCompany

Comment: Please explain better you question i don't understand

Comment: show the related query ..

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, any empty cell should be null unless you are entering an empty string.

You could hard-code queries for each column to get a result like the one you are asking for, but you would have to do a query for each column.

```
SELECT id, 'nameMusicCompany'
FROM tablename 
WHERE nameMusicCompany = null;
```

or

```
SELECT id, 'nameMusicCompany'
FROM tablename 
WHERE nameMusicCompany = '';
```

or

```
SELECT id, 'nameMusicCompany'
FROM tablename 
WHERE nameMusicCompany = null 
OR nameMusicCompany = '';
```